# How to Home Network several devices

Tags: networking, connectivity

## This is a little bit about Home Networking

i have this challenge that i want to Network my devices (smartphone, laptop, tablets)

**This is the case:**

I have a laptop that contains all my files (songs, pc games, movies, ebooks etc.). this laptop has keyboard problem and is static as the case maybe;
Now, i want to create a Home Network scene whereby I can access any of these files (by access i mean, view, copy/download any of the files without an internet connectivity) WIRELESSLY from any of my devices (smartphone, tablet, pcs) when they connect to the laptops' Network.

**so it'll be more like**

pc, tablet, or phone connects to the static laptop Network, then searches through and then copy any file(s) that is inside that static latop.

i've heard and tried HomeGroup that comes with windows, but i think it's only limited to pc and pc connectivity. and other devices(phones) can not access it

*Please, is this my request possible, even if it requires a third party software? if YES, let me know so i can get it started...pls*

Comment: try http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

You have at least a couple of options:

1. Run a server on the laptop to expose the directories you want to share (media server, FTP, NFS, etc.)
2. Share the files using a remote storage solution (MS OneDrive, Google Drive, Box, etc.)

The first solution is more likely to be compatible with most devices and require less setup (no need to install special software on each client), but is also less secure as it exposes the files to any device on the network.

The second solution requires an app on each client but provides the greatest level of security and control over content and access.

Comment: yea, i'll check the first option, but the thing with the second option is that i rather not want any of the devices to be connected with internet, just you know home network since they are within range and connected to same wireless network. security ain't an issues since it will be in house..#just saying

Comment: Then the first option is your best choice.  If the data is all media (music, video), then consider running a DLNA server, as most devices will auto discover it.

Comment: Ok thanks.ive actually gotten a method. http://www.howtogeek.com/191378/how-to-access-shared-windows-folders-on-android-ipad-and-iphone/